# how to remove message queue that is created by msgget

Tags: c, system-calls

I created message queue with `msgget` function.
Below code is snippet of it.

```
key_t msg_queue_key_id = msgget((key_t)MQ_KEY, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
if( msg_queue_key_id == -1 ) {
    char error_log[MAX_LENGTH];
    sprintf(error_log, "failed to create message queue. errno = %d", errno);
    ERROR_LOGGING(error_log)
    return 1;
}
```

I meet errno 17 because there is already message queue that I created.
Unhappily, I can't find how to remove message queue. I also see `mq_unlink` function, but it deson't looks like for this case.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A message queue created with `msgget` is removed with [`msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, 0)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgctl.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found.... use linux command `ipcrm`

`ipcrm -q {{messag_queue_key}}`

We can also see message queue list by using `ipcs -q`